# Kafka Streams local state store size increasing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have written a kafka stream processor using the processor api. I am cleaning up state stores with punctuation in regular intervals. But I am still seeing local state store sizes gradually increasing. Now it has reached GBs.
Would somebody please let me know the reason?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you're cleaning up the state stores?

Comment: Additionally, what's the throughput of new messages being cached vs old messages being deleted?